# How to run production build locally using webpack server?

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack-dev-server locally to build my application. I have configure it properly and on running command "yarn build" its generating files into /dist/ folder.

Is there any way I can use the dist folder locally using the webpack-dev-server? The idea is I need to run multiple versions of my application locally to test few stuf.

Comment: You can try use [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/)

Answer (score 12):

You need a server to serve your generated dist folder.

You can use (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server):

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Jump into your dist folder and run:

```
http-server
```

Comment: It works just fine, thank you